# ColdFusion - Looping through a nested structure in an array

Tags: arrays, json, coldfusion, structure, nested-loops

I have a json retuned from an external API:

```
{ "data" : { "consignmentDetail" : [ { "consignmentNumber" : "5995600864",
            "parcelNumbers" : [ "15505995600864" ]
          } ],
      "consolidated" : false,
      "shipmentId" : "60764454"
    },
  "error" : null
}
```

I can get the `shipmentId` value by deserializing the JSON and grabbing `data.ShipmentId`. I really need to get the value of `consignmentNumber` too, but when I try to loop through the array as a collection I'm getting an error:

> "Invalid collection
>   [{parcelNumbers={[15505995603009]},consignmentNumber={5995603009}}].
>   Must be a valid structure or COM object. "

The code I have so far is:

```
<cfset consignmentDetailArray = [] >
<cfset consignmentDetailArray = shipmentData.data.consignmentDetail>
<cfset mystruct ={}>

<cfloop collection=#consignmentDetailArray# item="i">
   <cfset myStruct = consignmentDetailArray[i]>
   <cfloop collection="#myStruct#" item="key">
      <cfoutput>#key#: #myStruct[key]#<br /></cfoutput>
   </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Any ideas what's causing the error? Is it because there is a structure in the array that is the value of `consignmentDetail`?
If so, any pointers on how to loop through that structure correctly?

I should maybe add that I'm very new to ColdFusion and still on a steep learning curve :)
(Running Coldfusion 10)

Thanks for reading and grateful for any help you can give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

consignmentDetalArray is an array, not a structure, and you are using cfloop collection=. You want to either loop from 1 to the len or use cfloop/array instead.

Here is one way to fix it:

```
<cfloop array="#consignmentDetailArray#" index="myStruct">
  <cfloop collection="#myStruct#" item="key">
    <cfoutput>#key#: #myStruct[key]#<br /></cfoutput>
  </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: That throws an error about invalid attributes. It works (doesn't error) if I do :
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(consignmentDetailArray)#" index="i">
      <cfloop collection="#myStruct#" item="key">
        <cfoutput>#key#: #myStruct[key]#<br /></cfoutput>
       </cfloop>
     </cfloop>

but that doesn't actually get anything out of the structure inside the array i.e nothing from cfoutput

Comment: Weird - I thought CF10 had cfloop array=... Oh! Oops, it is index="myStruct", not item.

Comment: @RaymondCamden Nice to hear from you on ColdFusion after a long time.

Comment: I never left, @Pankaj.